# De'Longhi 7 qt stand mixer

Tags: equipment

I have a De'Longhi 7 qt. stand mixer that I believe is now manufactured by Kenwood in America. I would love to make pasta but the attachment is no longer available. Can I use those made by KitchenAid? Will they fit?

Comment: I doubt (but am not sure) that different manufacturers' attachments will be interchangeable. You could maybe look for used or third-party attachments, though.

Comment: https://www.kenwoodworld.com/en-us/products/kitchen-machines/chef-and-major-attachments

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. The Delonghi/Kenwood mixers have a different attachment interface than KitchenAid, with a hexagonal shank and a different mechanism for retaining the attachment.